# Unable to get the correct URL using get_the_post_thumbnail_url() in wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, post-thumbnails, rest-api

I've added some custom fields to a rest route. I want to retrive the post thumbnail for my CPT and I'm using this code:

This is the code I'm using to add the post meta to the CPT after an image is selected and the post is published. If not clear I'm not using the default WP UI but a customnized one based on vue.js

```php
                    $post_published = wp_update_post( 
                        array(
                            'ID' => $post_id,
                            'meta_input' => array(
                                'post_thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id )
                            ),
                            'post_status' => 'publish'
                        ), 
                        true, 
                        true 
                    );
```

The url will look like this
`localhost/wp-content/uploads/23/09/myimage.png` and into the wp-admin custom dashboard the system will  try to load this kind of url `http://localhost/mysite/wp-admin/localhost/mysite/resources/uploads/2023/09/customimage-min-2.png`

Anyway I've noticed that in my customized wordpress dashboard the link will be loaded in a wrong way, by inspecting the DOM I've noticed that the url of the thumbnail will be appended to the wp-admin one and this will result in a failed load. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just to be clear, this `post_thumbnail` is not the featured image that comes with WordPress but a brand new and totally separate post meta? Featured images aren't stored as URLs, and it's not ideal to store raw URLs in the database if they're referring to posts as it deprives you the opportunity to filter them and can leave you with stale values when things change and the need to perform a search replace. E.g. if the thumbnail attachment was deleted there'd be no way to tell from that meta value if it was still valid without a slow DB query or a HTTP request, which isn't an issue with IDs

Comment: post thumbnail is a custom value I'm storing into the database, in this case I'm saving the url of the uploaded file. I need to have a cleean url to be able to load it using REST API since at the moment also the editor isn't the default one of WP

Comment: hmm that's useful to know but answered none of my questions. Can you expand further upon where/how/when the PHP code you mentioned in your question is executed? Also the sentence that comes after your code block is very difficult to parse and understand, can you rewrite it, as well as what you meant by "loaded in a wrong way"? Try to avoid implied statements and state things directly and unambiguously. Also include the full _raw_ version of what got saved and stored in the database, it looks like the examples in your question are the final output

Comment: @TomJNowell the code is executed after post is inserted into the database using insert post function. Since I want to be able to see all the files inside the standard wordpress UI I've used the wp_upload_media function to upload the image. At the moment I'm thinking to switch to the default Wordpress UI for CPT, but in this case I'm unable to see the featureb image box also if I enable the feature when the cpt is registered, and also by adding theme support

Comment: is that in a REST API endpoint/Admin AJAX handler/a hook on the core REST API endpoints? How is `$post_id` being set? There's not enough code to diagnose the problem with what you shared. It's also unclear how you're testing this value wether it's the database value or if it's in the raw JSON response from the API, or if it's just the final processed output in the DOM once all code has executed

Comment: it's into the callback of a custom rest endpoint that will save posts into database.

Comment: hmmm you didn't answer my question about how you're testing this and where the value is. Without knowing that it's ultra difficult to figure out where the `http`/`https` is being stripped to produce `localhost/wp-content/uploads/23/09/myimage.png`, or if it was ever inserted at all. Figuring that out without the answer would mean seeing significantly more code so that it could be reproduced locally